# If $p=3n$ and $n=6$, what's the value of $p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it $18$? I'm not to sure, that's why I have asked. I'm thinking if a number precedes a letter then you times it, is this correct?

Comment: $3n$ means "multiply 3 and n," so you are correct.

Comment: Why the downvotes? A mathematics question is being asked and even a little effort is shown. Apparenly some here downvot because of the level of the question.

Comment: @Matta: Obviously you haven't tried that yourself. Try it now, go on, and see how far it gets you. And next time, think before you condescend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p=3n$ and it is given $n=6$.

So,by the method of substitution of $n$ for $6$ we have $p=3\times6=18.$

So,you are correct!!